# Selecting only one record (Javabean, setAttribute, getAttribute, SQL, servlet)

Tags: java, servlets, return, javabeans

I created a new bean called `client` with `Id`, `Name`, `LastName` and `Address` fields. I created the model and the view of course. My model returns a list of all the clients. And this one is working fine.

But I need a model where I can select only one specific client filtered by `Id`. Can anybody tell me what I need to change (besides the SQL statement) inside this model so I get only one client according to filter (id) criteria from SQL?

```
{
    Connection connection = getDatabaseConnection();
    request.setAttribute("clientList", getClientList(connection));
    closeDatabaseConnection(connection);
}

private ArrayList<Client> getClientList(Connection con)
{
    String sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM Clients";
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();

    try
    {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            Client client = new Client();
            client.setId(rs.getInt("Id"));
            client.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
            client.setLastName(rs.getString("LastName"));
            client.setAddress(rs.getString("Address"));

            clients.add(client);
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        return clients;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess you already have a class with a method that you invoke to retrieve all the cliets, right?

Well, now add another method, but this time a method that receives the client Id as parameter:

```
public List<Client> getAllClients();
public Client getClientById(int clientId);
```

You will need a secondary SQL statement, since the logic in the first one is for retrieving all records. Something like:

```
"select clientId, clientName, ... from clients where clientId=?"
```

Using a JDBC PreparedStatement you can easily replace the ? for the actual parameter being received by your API.

You can also consider abstracting your mapping strategy so that you can use it for both methods:

```
class ClientMapper implements SqlMapper<Client> {
    @Override
    public Client map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
       Client client = new Client();
       client.setId(rs.getInt("Id"));
       client.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
       client.setLastName(rs.getString("LastName"));
       client.setAddress(rs.getString("Address"));
       return client;
    }
}
```

You can also have a ClientsMapper that uses this single client mapper to retrieve all clients.

```
class ClientsMapper implements SqlMapper<List<Client>>{
   @Override
   public List<Client> map(ResultSet rs){
     List<Client> result = new ArrayList<>();
     ClientMapper mapper = new ClientMapper();
     while(rs.next()){
        result.add(mapper.map(rs));
     }
     return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: For the first question answer is yes. The idea with second method is not bad option actually. I think I am starting to follow You :) Basically, can You tell me what modification I should do in my code above to get just one client filtered by id. This method sets all clients in the database. What would look like method that sets values for only one client.

Comment: I'd wrap `rs.next()` inside an `if`, else this may throw a nice `SQLException` on resultset `get` calls when it didn't return any record (i.e. when the given ID doesn't exist in the DB).

Comment: @BalusC I was assuming you would not invoke the mapper unless there are results in the resultset. It's better not to go down that hole, because if you check that here, you would be forced to return null objects, which is always a bad idea.

Comment: Why are you calling `rs.next()` in the mapper then? Just do `if (rs.next()) { client = map(rs); }`. This way it's also better reuseable for multiple results, `while (rs.next()) { clients.add(map(rs)); }`.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo - Thanks for explanation. That is what I was asking for.

Comment: @BalusC That may be probably wrong as well. My point is that this mapper could be used to map also the items in the other method that returns a list. So, perhaps the ClientListMapper could deal with the ResultSet traversal, or we could leave it here, as you suggest and deal with possible exceptional cases.

Comment: Btw, how should I implement exception if i got more than one result in this case?

Comment: Why would you throw an exception if there are no (more) records? That makes no sense. Just return `null` or empty list respectively if there's no record(s). @user: think again, how is it possible that you get more than one result in case of a query with a WHERE clause on a PK/unique column?

Comment: @user1759059 If you are searching by the client Id, there should be only one record (or none), but never more than one. Otherwise you are using the wrong key and you should consider returning a list of clients again, but this time with only those satisfying your filtering criterium.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo - Yeah, I completelly understand Your concerns, this is just theoretical question :)

Comment: @BalusC I have extended my answer to make my point clear. I have got rid of the rs.next() to demonstrate the point.

Comment: @user1759059 if this answered your question, please mark this post as the answer in Stackoverflow. We don’t do this just for the fun of it, we're after the points as well :-)

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo - Yes off course. I search for that option, but couldn't find it. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by besides sql statement?You will have to add a where clause to the query.I don't think it's possible any other case.

Comment: Thats what I thoughr by saying besides sql statement.

Comment: yes, there's no such a way using PreparedStatement or Statement. However, you it is surely possible in some ORM frameworks. For example, it is possible in Hibernate with the help of Criteria and Restrictions APIs.

Answer (score 0):

well you can have one more method that returns a single client based on the id you provide as argument.

```
 public Client getClientById(int id){
    //fetch the client data using the id

    //make a local Client object
    Client c = new Client();

    //populate c based on the values you get from your database.

    //return this local object of Client
    return c;

 }
```